# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}', failing to dynamically access fields

Tags: typescript

> **The elementary question my problem would fall down to is: How do we program with heterogeneous
> Maps in TS? (a map where values are not of the same type). Because
> from that moment, the type changes depending on the key you used to
> pick an object.**

No matter what I try, I can't get rid of the error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    test/db/mongoose/mocks/loadOffersTestsPrefill.ts:178:19 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
      No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

    178     otherFields = mockDef?.[specific] as Record<string, unknown>;
```

Below is my code: I have a nice central object where I'm setting all the mocks I need for a test. Each mock stored in the Map `MOCKS` can contain free form objects that will be used by another method when building the real objects: `preparePredefinedOffer()`.

The following common fields don't pose any issue, even though they are not present in all config objects (only common is present in the unique object i'm showing in this example). How does TS know these 3 fields exist in the map values? (common, monthly, yearly)

```
const { common, monthly, yearly } = mockDef as Record<string, Record<string, unknown>>;
```

But as soon as I try to access a non hardcoded field, one that will be resolved as the runtime value of `specific`, the code fails. I can't use the **keyof typeof** syntax as I'm dealing with a Map containing undeclared object types.

Any ideas on how to solve that please? (I wouldn't like to declare all the possible fields next to the three mentioned above: (common, monthly, yearly)

```
MOCKS.set(OFFER_GROUP.VipSeoBackLinks, {
  common: {
    cycle: "monthly", // ends at the end of the year
    offerGroup: "VIP_BACK_LINK",
    tags: ["vip"]
  },
  _1_article: {
    name: "1 article/month",
    overridingKey: "1link",
    price: 640,
    tokenCount: 1 // one event
  },
  _2_articles: {
    name: "2 articles/month",
    overridingKey: "2links",
    price: 1280,
    tokenCount: 2 // one event
  }
});

/* eslint-enable */
async function preparePredefinedOffer(
  offerDao: IOfferDao<ObjectId, IOffer<ObjectId>>,
  offerGroup: OFFER_GROUP,
  specific?: string,
) {
  const mockDef = MOCKS.get(offerGroup);
  const { common, monthly, yearly } = mockDef as Record<
    string,
    Record<string, unknown>
  >;
  let otherFields: Record<string, unknown>;

  if (specific == null) {
    otherFields = {};
  } else if (specific == "m") {
    otherFields = monthly;
    otherFields.offerGroup = offerGroup;
    otherFields.cycle = "monthly";
    otherFields.overridingKey = "monthly-" + offerGroup;
  } else if (specific == "y") {
    otherFields = yearly;
    otherFields.offerGroup = offerGroup;
    otherFields.cycle = "yearly";
    otherFields.overridingKey = "yearly-" + offerGroup;
  } else {
    otherFields = mockDef?.[specific] as Record<string, unknown>;
    if (otherFields == null) {
      console.warn(
        "No special field found in mock ",
        offerGroup,
        " with key: ",
        specific,
      );
    }
  }
  const offer = offerDao.build({
    ...baseRootOffer,
    ...common,
    ...otherFields,
  });

  return offer;
}
```

> I'm working on an open source project, I can share the entire file: I
> just pushed it on a [separate](https://github.com/ziedHamdi/UserCredits/tree/offer-unlocked-by-field) branch [here](https://github.com/ziedHamdi/UserCredits/blob/offer-unlocked-by-field/test/db/mongoose/mocks/loadOffersTestsPrefill.ts)

**Edit:**

I was able to solve that by making my Map a regular object, and scanning all values building a union type like follows:

```
type MockType = {
  [key in OFFER_GROUP]: {
    [subKey: string]: any;
  };
};

/**
 * A little tricky:  Captures the value types union of T and uses them as UnionFromMockType (instead of T)
 */
type UnionFromMockType<T> = T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: infer U;
  }
  ? U
  : never;

type CompleteMockType = UnionFromMockType<MockType[OFFER_GROUP]>;

const MOCKS: MockType = {
  Free: {},
  Startup: {
    common: {},
    monthly: {
      price: 49,
      tags: ["subscription", "standard", "monthly"]
    },
    yearly: {
      price: 490,
      tags: ["subscription", "standard", "yearly"]
    }
  },
```

And then using that like follows:

```
async function preparePredefinedOffer(
  offerDao: IOfferDao<ObjectId, IOffer<ObjectId>>,
  offerGroup: OFFER_GROUP,
  specific?: string,
) {
  const mockDef: CompleteMockType = MOCKS[offerGroup];
  const { common, monthly, yearly } = mockDef;
  let otherFields: Record<string, unknown>;
```

> **But I let the question open because my understanding is that Typescript killed Maps, a concept that was widely used in js, by
> drastically limiting its use to homogeneous Maps (or to be more precise: compile-time-known value types Maps)**

Comment: "Typescript killed Maps, a concept that was widely used in js" --- `{
    [k: string]: any;
}` <- wouldn't this be a "js map"?

Comment: Map is originally an object where you call .put(key, value) and subsequently retrieve it with .get(key). 
I think the Typescript syntax is lacking a keyword that would mean (let me do my thing here). In cases like unit tests, we don't need to have the same rigor just to construct some mock objects

Comment: _I think the Typescript syntax is lacking a keyword that would mean (let me do my thing here)._ Isn't that `any`?